# How to create attachment from Rest Api Javascript

Tags: rest-api, attachment, ajax-toolkit

I want to create attachment from javascript to salesforc using REST api without using Ajax Toolkit.

I tried with this link [Create Document using REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm)

But I had no luck .

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: This one is the same link I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

use Forcetk javascript library as follows - https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit

please find below is the sample code -

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" title="File Uploader">
```

#### Select a file to upload as a new Chatter File.

var client = new forcetk.Client();

```
client.setSessionToken('{!$Api.Session_ID}');

function upload() {
    var file = $("#file")[0].files[0];
    client.createBlob('ContentVersion', {
        Origin: 'H', // 'H' for Chatter File, 'C' for Content Document
        PathOnClient: file.name
    }, file.name, 'VersionData', file, function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $("#message").html("Chatter File created: <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/" + response.id + "\">Take a look!</a>");
    }, function(request, status, response){
        $("#message").html("Error: " + status);
    });
}
```

You can refer to this question and answer as well - [Uploading attachments using ForceTk](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80616/uploading-attachments-using-forcetk)